# Get touch location from touchesBegan? (And other game questions)

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, touch

I'm trying to get the location of the touch event on the screen from

`-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.

What code can I use to read the touch coordinates? I've gotten this far so far:

```
NSLog(@"Touch data: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NSSet: %@",[touches description]]);
```

I'm trying to make a game using an OpenGL template application. The touches will only register in the `EAGLView` file, not the `ESRenderer1` file.  I assume that I should use the EAGlView to set variables and then read the variables from there into the ESRenderer to perform game calculations. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following code does it:

```
NSArray *touchesArray = [touches allObjects];
for(int i=0; i<[touchesArray count]; i++)
{
    UITouch *touch = (UITouch *)[touchesArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:nil];

    // do something with 'point'
}
```

Comment: I'd choose to use `for (UITouch *touch in touches) {/*...*/}` instead. (Fast enumeration!)

Comment: What if I just want the latest touch, none of the other information? How would this work?

Comment: I think that array is a list of the "latest" touches in that it represents where finger(s) currently are on the screen. Most of the time, the array will only have one element for most applications.